# Making a SQL Server connection in Visual Studio 2008 for smart device application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am tyring to create a scanner application and this requires going into my database and fetching a upc code. However I don't know how to accomplish this in visual studio. Essentially when a person clicks a button a database connection should open from the smart device which will allow the user to see the price of an item. However I was struggling trying to create a a database connection so I tried doing it by my odbc driver which is how I use it for my access programs. This worked and I can see all my tables on my server explorer. However I don't know if I have to explicitly establish a connection pragmatically as well in order to run a select statement....

I forgot to mention I decided to go with an ODBC connection because when I tried sing Microsoft Sql Server (SQLCLient) I got an error saying `"The server version is not supported only servers up to Microsoft Sql Server 2005 are supported"`

So I decided to go with the odbc driver but I don't even know if using an odbc driver will work while using the application on the scanner device

I haven't programming with VS nor vb.net so this is all pretty new to me, so any pointers at all help

Comment: You generally wouldn't make a direct connection to a database from a device like that. Usually the device would connect to a web service and the web service would connect to the database.

Comment: what about using this method of connection https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/trusted-connection-from-a-ce-device/ and or linking them this way, I included the link for this one as well http://dev.cs.ovgu.de/db/sybase9/help/dbpgen9/00000268.htm